# Will Wordpress work with MySQL Master Master replication?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am looking at creating a high availability Wordpress installation across two servers with a load balancer to distribute the traffic between these servers, I intend to setup a LAMP stack on these two web servers and configure MySQL master master replication to ensure both servers have the same content similar to the setup at https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/cms/high-availability-wordpress

For anyone created a similar setup before, is there anything to watch out for? Will this work without there being differences in the database assuming both nodes are online? If one node goes down will this synchronise with the other master node successfully?

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty old post, but I've set up exactly this recently.

I do not recommend setting up WordPress with master-master replication. The nodes went out of sync multiple times and resulted in split-brain. We've reverted back to master-slave replication because of the instability of the setup.

Answer (score 1):

I recently tried this and regret it. I realize your post is now almost 2 years old, but thought I should put in my 2 cents for anyone considering this approach. I recommend you go with MariaDB with MaxScale to separate the reads and writes, and go with master-slave configuration. I'm running into all sorts of deadlocks, and issues with this configuration. Currently using MariaDB with Galera, with HAProxy up front.